# How to reference another table with a consistent primary key across tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables which both have a unique PID.  I need to know how I should setup the primary/foreign keys so I can access fields from both tables in one SQL statement.

For example: With the following data structure i'd like to echo out the players name and photo but also echo out all their stats via PHP as well.  I have successfully done this with just the player Stats, but I do not know how to get access to fields in another table.

Here is my database structure so far:

```
Players
-PID (Set as Primary Key)
-Name
-Height
-College
-Photo

Stats
-PID 
-Touchdowns
-Receptions
```

Current PHP Code:

```
$query="
SELECT * FROM Stats    
ORDER BY Stats.FantasyPoints DESC";

$res=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($res);
$i=0;

while($i< $num){
$Name = mysql_result($res, $i, "Name");
$FantasyPoints = mysql_result($res, $i, "FantasyPoints");

echo $Name . ': '. $FantasyPoints . "<br />";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Show us how you would access either table separately.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html

Comment: Your data model is unclear; I would think `touchdown` and `reception` would belong to `gamestats`, and `playerstats` as described would be an aggregate. Or something like that (and more columns than I'm suggesting, too).

Comment: Added code that i'm using to access the tables separately

Comment: Why have two tables in the first place? If your model is really that simple then I would create one Player table with nullable touchdowns and receptions columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "
SELECT p.*, s.*
FROM Players AS p
LEFT JOIN Stats AS s ON p.PID = s.PID
ORDER BY s.FantasyPoints DESC
";
```

You could also use a JOIN rather than a LEFT JOIN which would limit the result to only players who have stats

Edited sql to produce result similar to your own sql.

======================================================

This is how I would go about it...

```
$query =
"
SELECT s.*, p.*
FROM Stats AS s
LEFT JOIN Players AS p ON p.PID = s.PID   
ORDER BY s.FantasyPoints DESC
";

$res = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    echo "{$row['name']}: {$row['FantasyPoints']}<br />";
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the PHP code i'm using and change your SQL statement

Comment: The p and the s are aliases for the table names (see `FROM Players as p`) it just makes it easier to come back later and add or remove columns from complicated sqls and is a habit I have got into.

Comment: So you writing AS s or AS p is what lets MySQL know that those are aliases for that table?

Comment: Thats right yes, from then on you reference the tables using their aliases for example: `SELECT thisisridiculous.*, omgwtfbbq.* FROM Players AS thisisridiculous LEFT JOIN Stats AS omgwtfbbq ON thisisridiculous.PID = omgwtfbbq.PID` That is a totally bad way of doing it but you should see what I'm implying.. In some of my work I might come across a table called staff_personal_data and I dont want to be typing that out a lot so I will reference (alias) it as spd

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp This has some great info on where and how you can use aliases if you're interested.